# Google Sheets IF and 2 x ANDS

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have three columns in my google sheet.

COL A - will hold an invoice number (text field) or be empty
COL B - will display the word `EXEPNSE`
COL C - this will be my formula column

I need to detect if column A contains anything and that column B contains the word expenses.

If COL A is blank AND COL B has the word `EXPENSE` show the word `ISSUE` in COL C otherwise just blank field.

This is what I have so far in Col C but am spinning my wheels.

```
=iferror(if(F9 = "EXPENSE",""),if(AND(isblank(E9),"ISSUE", "")))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A="")*(B2:B="EXPENSE"), "ISSUE", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

for one cell/row evaluation paste in **C2** and drag down:

```
=IF((A2="")*(B2="EXPENSE"), "ISSUE", )
```

#### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mo55PqV2uEehuMaUZaB5DwLN30fQJRxyOkeDLRXJuy8/edit#gid=0&range=C2)

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**. Please describe how this post answers the question.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and did not work, but gave me some direction.

In the end this work: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E7="")*(F7="EXPENSE"), "ISSUE", )) I have upvoted you though for thanks.

Comment: @CraigEdmonds well, glad your issue is solved, tho I failed to understand what is the difference between this suggested solution and your "answer". next time provide a copy of your sheet so we could craft you a formula that will fit exactly in your scenario. I updated the answer and included spreadsheet demo which proves it's working as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In the end this the solution in Google Sheets.

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E10="")*(F10="EXPENSE"), "ISSUE", ))

Thanks to [@user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0) for their suggestion.

[image: screen shot]